# How to communicate between microservices (request/response)

Tags: microservices

can anyone help on below issue?

I have two microservices A and B where service A sends request to B, B fetches data from database and sends the response back to A, based on received data, I am doing few operations.
At present, I am using Http client call.I don't want to use http request? How can I proceed further?

Thanks,
Revathi

Comment: You can perform a Socket or Web Socket connection between the two microservices. Decide a protocol that A and B understands, or a generic protocol that all microservices will understand and transfer data based on operations. You can send operation ID to classify each packet's purpose or by name. Don't forget to add validation if you are not using a local network between the microservices. If you could explain the reason why you don't want to use HTTP or what are you planning to do, some context, it will help me give you a better and detailed answer.

Comment: data (configuration data) which is fetched by service B changes rarely. So instead of making http call , I would like to store it in some cache so I can improve performance

Comment: You could store it in Redis, and update that cache every time you need either with an endpoint call or a scheduled cron job

Comment: Thank you Ben!! I will try Redis DB

Comment: Ben, using Redis cache or gRPC is better for my use case? can you share your thoughts please?

Comment: I am not experienced with gRPC so I can't really answer that. But if you really just need caching, I'd go for Redis. Looks like gRPC is a buffer-like approach for HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTTP to communicate between 2 services, you need a HTTP client that allows you to specify the parameters related to your request. Example in Java (more details [here](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)):

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
     .uri(URI.create("<YOUR_ENDPOINT>"))
     .build();
client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
     .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
     .thenAccept(System.out::println)
     .join();
```

If you don't want to use HTTP 1.1, you can take a look at [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/), there are plenty examples on the web on how to use both of them

Comment: Isn't gRPC using HTTP/2 ?